# Cassandra TimeUUID flood file descriptor when use uuid in default

Tags: python, cassandra, timeuuid, clustering-key

I have Cassandra model as

```
import uuid
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model

class MyModel(Model):
    ...
    ...
    created_at = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                         clustering_order='DESC',
                         default=uuid.uuid1)
    ...
    ...
```

Recentrly app hit the [uuid1 creation doesn't close files - hits file descriptor limit](https://github.com/dln/python-libuuid/issues/1). I try to find the solution, but seems what options I think might be not work

- Replace `uuid1` in default with `uuid4`, but `TimeUUID` need time part in it, and only `uuid1` provide that.
- Relace `uuid1` with `cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time())`, when check the code for both [`uuid1`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/uuid.py#L622:L62) and [`uuid_from_time`](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/master/cassandra/util.py#L129), both are looks same, so that also not solve the problem.

Last option is to replace `TimeUUID` with `Timestamp` type, but this `created_at` column is `primary_key` and `clustering_order`, so dont know I can do that or not.

My column family has already 1,000,000+ data, so I cant just drop them.

I also want to know, what is the advantage of using `TimeUUID` instead of `timestamp` ?

Comment: Why don't you use datastax python-driver's timeuuid generation ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam can you give example ? how to apply your solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain you're hitting the `libuuid` issue you linked? Your code snippet shows the standard library `uuid`, which probably doesn't have that issue. Is it possible there's a different file descriptor leak in your program?

If it is `libuuid`, the easiest course would be to use the standard library implementation. If speed is a major concern for you, you might look into building a different version of `libuuid` to use with `python-libuuid`. I tried this one quickly and didn't notice any file descriptors leaking: http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/

> I also want to know, what is the advantage of using TimeUUID instead of timestamp ?

You won't be able to change the type of the column on your existing table, but to answer your question: TimeUUID is usually used to avoid collisions where multiple events could be written in the same timestamp value.

Comment: Adam, I am hitting the same issue which I linked. I am now using https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/util.html#cassandra.util.uuid_from_time now to generate new `uuid`

Comment: You are using the driver utility method and hitting [this](https://github.com/dln/python-libuuid/issues/1) issue? That would be very surprising unless you're somehow monkey patching the `uuid` standard library. Are you?
What symptoms lead you to believe it's the same issue?

Comment: Is there any way to check, I am using `uuid` form `libuuid` or `standard` uuid ?

Comment: Unless you are monkey patching somewhere else, your code snippet indicates that you're using the standard lib version. You can verify by `import uuid; print uuid.__file__`. It should be something like `.../lib/python2.7/uuid.pyc` and not `.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/libuuid/__init__.pyc`

Comment: Thanks Adam, will check this