# Use cassandra inbuild `now()` function to generate TimeUUID with Model in Python driver

Tags: python, cassandra, model, timeuuid, datastax-python-driver

I have code as

```
import time

from uuid import uuid4

import cassandra
from cassandra.cqlengine.models import Model
from cassandra.cqlengine.query import BatchQuery
from cassandra.cqlengine import columns, connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table


class StudentModel(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'student'
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    created_timestamp = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                                         clustering_order='DESC',
                                         default=cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time()))
    name = columns.Text(required=True, default='')

class ClassRoomModel(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'class_room'
    id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    created_timestamp = columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                                         clustering_order='DESC',
                                         default=cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time()))
    name = columns.Text(required=True, default='')

class StudentToClass(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'student_to_class_mapping'
    class_room_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    created_timestamp = \
        columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                         clustering_order='DESC',
                         default=cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time()))
    student_id = columns.UUID()

class ClassToStudent(Model):
    __table_name__ = 'class_to_student_mapping'
    student_id = columns.UUID(primary_key=True)
    created_timestamp = \
        columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                         clustering_order='DESC',
                         default=cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time()))
    class_room_id = columns.UUID()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection.setup(hosts=['localhost'],
                     default_keyspace='test')
    sync_table(StudentModel)
    sync_table(ClassRoomModel)
    sync_table(StudentToClass)
    sync_table(ClassToStudent)

    students = []
    for i in xrange(100):
        students.append(StudentModel.create(name='student' + str(i)))

    class_room = ClassRoomModel.create(name='class1')

    for student in students:
        print "Creating batch for: ", student.name
        with BatchQuery() as batch_query:
            ClassToStudent.batch(batch_query).create(
                student_id=student.id, class_room_id=class_room.id)
            StudentToClass.batch(batch_query).create(
                student_id=student.id, class_room_id=class_room.id)
```

This code works fine, and it created records too. When I check the records count, it match for 3 tables, but for `test.student_to_class_mapping`, it has to be 100, but it gives only `1`.

```
cqlsh> select count(*) from test.student;

 count
-------
   100

(1 rows)
cqlsh> select count(*) from test.class_room ;

 count
-------
     1

(1 rows)
cqlsh> select count(*) from test.class_to_student_mapping;

 count
-------
   100

(1 rows)
cqlsh> select count(*) from test.student_to_class_mapping ;

 count
-------
     1

(1 rows)
```

I found the issue, logic wise its correct, only issue is `clusturing_key` in `test.student_to_class_mapping`.

```
created_timestamp = \
    columns.TimeUUID(primary_key=True,
                     clustering_order='DESC',
                     default=cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time()))
```

`cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time())` is not able to generate `Unique` uuid for each record. I can use `uuid1` but I already face issue with [`uuid1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807341/cassandra-timeuuid-flood-file-descriptor-when-use-uuid-in-default).

I know, we can use [`now()`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html), I change my code to

```
from cassandra.query import BatchStatement, SimpleStatement
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
...
...
    batch_query = BatchStatement()
    batch_query.add(
        SimpleStatement('INSERT INTO {0} '
            '("student_id", "created_timestamp", "class_room_id") '
            'VALUES ({1}, now(), {2})'.format(
                StudentToClass.column_family_name(),
                student.id, class_room.id)))
    batch_query.add(
        SimpleStatement('INSERT INTO {0} '
            '("student_id", "created_timestamp", "class_room_id") '
            'VALUES ({1}, now(), {2})'.format(
                ClassToStudent.column_family_name(),
                student.id, class_room.id)))   
    connection.session.execute(batch_query) 
...
...
```

Now its working fine and creating all records as per logic.

I want to know that, is there any way to use `now()` with Model's `create` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happend:

> ```
> default = None
>     the default value, can be a value or a callable (no args)
> ```

(from https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/columns.html)

Your line with

```
default=cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time())
```

got evaluated at startup time and contained a single value as uuid. Try something like this:

```
from uuid import uuid1,uuid4

class Comment(Model):
    photo_id = UUID(primary_key=True)
    comment_id = TimeUUID(primary_key=True, default=uuid1) # second primary key component is a clustering key
    comment = Text()
```

Found here. https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/cqlengine/query.html

Another (pure personal) remark - generate the uuid explicit as one often need it afterwards ;)

Comment: Thanks Jan, I already face issue with `uuid1`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807341/cassandra-timeuuid-flood-file-descriptor-when-use-uuid-in-default

Comment: if you can give me example to use `now()` that will be very helpful.

Comment: If you use uuid from pythons standard libs there should be no problem at all - the only open file handle issue I know about comes from libuuid (which is faster).

Comment: What you also could do is simply meet the requirement for non agrument functions:

´def genUUID():
  cassandra.util.uuid_from_time(time.time())
`

and then use my.package.genUUID for default.

Comment: Thanks Jan, for giving all this option, but my requirement is to use `now()` cassandra function in `Model`.